# auto discover restful api with Silex

Tags: rest, silex, restful-architecture

is it possible to make Silex expose the API structure automatically?
What I mean is that I'd like to have a full list of the API endpoints, generated automatically by Silex, on the base of the routes I have defined in the code.
If this is not possible, which other frameorks allow to achieve this?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use https://github.com/jdesrosiers/silex-swagger-provider – which is a Silex provider for https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php.

Alternatively, for Symfony, there’s the NelmioApiDocBundle, which might also be usable in a Silex project.

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in way to do that.

You can access the registered routes via `$app["routes"]`, which is a Sf2 RouteCollection instance. You can iterate over this and generate what you need.